# Configure mouse in Dragonfly BSD - VirtualBox Guest

Tags: dragonfly-bsd

How do you configure the mouse in Dragonfly BSD installed as VirtualBox Guest?

- **Host:** Ubuntu 17.10 running VirtualBox 5.1.30
- **Guest:** [Dragonfly BSD](https://www.dragonflybsd.org) version 5.0.2

I configured the `VirtualBox VM` for DrangonFly as follows.

- **General\Name:** DragonFlyBSD
- **General\Operating System:** FreeBSD (64-bit)
- **System\Base Memory:** 1024 MB
- **System\Processors:** 2
- **System\Pointing Device:** PS/2 Mouse
- **Display\Video Memory:** 32 MB
- **Display\Acceleration:** 3D
- **Audio\Host Driver:** ALSA Audio Driver
- **Audio\Controller:** Intel HD Audio
- **USB\Enable USB Controller:** Checked
- **USB\USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller:** Checked

When I created my user account I set the "other group memberships" field to wheel, video.

I installed xorg as follows, following the instructions found on the [DragonFly BSD X](https://www.dragonflybsd.org/docs/handbook/X/) page.

```
pkg install xorg
```

When I run *startx*, the mouse cursor is visible but no matter what I do, the mouse cursor does not move.

Running *Xorg -configure* made no difference .

I cannot find any information on how to install `VirtualBox OSE` Additions on DragonFly BSD.

The following command yields no results.

```
pkg search virtualbox-ose-additions
```

Does anyone have information on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a good question, just not programming related.  So not great for SO.  Could somebody move it to https://unix.stackexchange.com ?  This question is near the top of answers for the topic on search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left out a step. When I added the following line to /etc/rc.conf, the mouse started working.

```
moused_enable="YES"
```